# converting GSL grammar to GRXML format

Tags: vxml

Are there any tools which would convert existing GSL grammar files to GRXML grammar files ?
I expected such a tool to be alread there but couldn't find it on searching, am I missing something ?

Answer (score 4):

The [NuEcho NuGram grammar development environment](http://nugram.nuecho.com/welcome) supports this:

> The NuGram platform natively support
>   the W3C's SRGS ABNF format with
>   extensions to support the development
>   of dynamic grammars. The ABNF format
>   was chosen since it is a W3C standard
>   and is without a doubt much more
>   readable and maintainable than the XML
>   format.
>
> Grammars can be translated to and from
>   other formats as well. The currently
>   supported languages are: GrXML (W3C
>   SRGS XML), and Nuance GSL.
>
> The NuGram platform also supports the
>   most widely used semantic tag
>   languages: W3C SISR (including the
>   SISR 2004 Working Draft syntax),
>   Nuance's GSL semantic tags, and
>   Nuance's OSR. tags.

Answer (score 0):

I take it you're currently upgrading from Nuance 8.5 or a previous version? If you are upgrading to the Nuance Recognizer 9-10 engines, there is a tool provided for converting between versions. It isn't a perfect conversion and the converted grammars normally need some modification/refinement, but it is a good starting point.